# NodeJs - Secure Web Socket and Client Connection

Tags: node.js, websocket

I need to convert an application with websocket in a secure-websocket. (under windows)
Im using nodeJs as websocket server and a simple html page to connect to it.

Searching on google and here, I found this approach:

Create a certificate and a key for server. I've followed this tutorial:

https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/

After creating a .key and a .pem, I'have modified my nodejs websocket server to introduce the certificate:

```
const httpsOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('./api/security/cert.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('./api/security/cert.pem')
}

this._http              = require('http');
this._server = this._http.createServer(httpsOptions , function(req, res) { this.closeCurrentConnections(req,res)}.bind(this));

var serverConfig = {
      server: this._server,
      autoAcceptConnections: false
}
this._wsServer = new WebSocketServer(serverConfig);
```

The Websocket server seems up when I start the nodejs

Now, in the client page I had this code:

```
var websocket_server    = "ws://localhost:8128";
var echo_service        = new WebSocket(websocket_server,"echo-protocol"); 

[...]
```

I changed it with the following code calling this page over HTTPS instead of simple HTTP:

```
var websocket_server    = "wss://localhost:8128";
var echo_service        = new WebSocket(websocket_server,"echo-protocol"); 

[...]
```

I got an error on client page:

```
testing_page.html:283 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8128/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I think is due to missing certificate. 
I've tried to import my previous create certificate on chrome but I cant import because chrome is especting a .crt and/or other format. I've tried to force .pem but it doens't work.

What Im missing?

[image]

Comment: just try open in Chrome a new tab `https://localhost:8128` and  and push on ADVANCED and Proceed to localhost (unsafe). After repeat connection on client tab.

Comment: Can you confirm that everything works for you without wss(ssl)?
So, if the problem is in ssl, i recommend you try ngrok(https://ngrok.com) for tests that need ssl on local machine.

Comment: Searching for a solution, I found an error in my code. When starting wss, I need https instead of http. this._http = require('https'). Then I have to try to connect via browser using https instead of wss and accept unsecure connection. Now the error is different: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404